# Keeping Outlook Specific Conditionals in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, outlook, xslt-1.0

I have an outlook specific conditional statement that I can't seem to get to render in XSL. I've tried saving them as variables and printing them, putting them in  tags... All with no luck.

Below is the code:

```
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    ... code ... 
    <![endif]-->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We definitely need more than this snippet to help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an outlook specific conditional statement that I can't seem to get to render in XSL.

What you are showing is an **XML comment** (`<!-- comment -->`) . Therefor you may try:

```
<xsl:comment>[if gte mso 9]>
... code ... 
&lt;![endif]</xsl:comment>
```

As an alternative you can use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` with `<![CDATA[`.  Try:

```
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
<![CDATA[  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
... code ... 
<![endif]--> ]]>
  </xsl:text>
```

Comment: CDATA worked for me too, but the problem is it prints `<xsl:choose>` statement as well in HTML.